# redirect lan peer's packets through my pc

Tags: networking, routes, lan, packet-capture

What I want to do is simple: in a WLAN suppose I have the ip 172.16.0.10, and my friend has 172.16.0.9. The router has ip 172.16.0.1, I want that all the traffic b/w my friend and router passes through my pc(which I could analyze using wireshark.)

I suppose this can be done using 'route add' command in linux which I can execute in his pc and set the metric to a lower value, but as I am new to these commands I can't figure out the exact way. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should enable routing on your machine. Something like `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. Also on the other machine, try: `ip route add default via 172.16.0.10`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the route command because the IPs are in the same subnet. Routing applicable only if the 2 IPs belongs to different network. Just put the router's IP as default gateway.